# Merge sort with n extra space

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, merge

I've created a Merge sort that is very inefficient with extra space usage. A new array is being created with every recursive call.  Without effecting the parameters of my functions, can I create a dynamic array that i'll only have to create and delete once?

```
void mergesort_normal(Item *A, int p, int r)
{

    int middle;
     if (p < r) {
      middle = p + (r - p) / 2;
      mergesort_normal(A, p, middle);
      mergesort_normal(A, middle +1, r);
      merge_normal(A, p, middle, r);
    }
  }

void merge_normal  (Item *A, int p, int mid, int r)
{
    Item *helper = new Item[r+1];
    int h = p;
    int i = p;
    int j = mid +1;
    int k = 0;


while((h<=mid)&&(j<=r))
{
    if(lessThan(A[h], A[j]))
    {
        helper[i]=key(A[h]);
        h++;
    }
    else
    {
        helper[i]=key(A[j]);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
 if(h>mid)
 {
    for(k=j;k<=r;k++)
    {
        helper[i]=key(A[k]);
        i++;
    }
 }
 else
 {
    for(k=h;k<=mid;k++)
    {
        helper[i]=key(A[k]);
        i++;
    }
 }
 for(k=p;k<=r;k++)
     A[k]=key(helper[k]);
}
```

Comment: This code is difficult to understand - it has no comments and almost every variable is only one letter in length.  Also, the indentation is off and the code doesn't seem to close the brackets.  The answer to your question is "probably" but we're not going to be able to help you if your algorighm is too obfuscated and incomplete to understand !

Comment: You're missing the delete of your merge-bed. Once the merge is done and you've copied back to the original sequence, so is the need for the temporary storage. I don't suppose you're at least allowed to use a `std::vector<>` for this? (its kind of obvious you can't use `std::merge` or `std::inplace_merge` if this is for academia). And i've not reviewed the actual algorithm so if its wrong, thats just another issue in itself.

Comment: Oh yes, there should be a delete at the end of the code. Yes, this is for school so I can't just use std::vector<> or std::merge. The algorithm works fine and perfectly sorts an array.

Comment: Ah. too bad. Sok, but just fyi you also don't need the two partitioning indexes either. Your mergesort_normal function can just take two parameters, a base address and a length. pointer arithmetic can do the partitioning. Think about it for awhile.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the parameters of the functions

Comment: Thats your instructors constriction. I was just telling you contrary to what some may think, both aren't needed. Anyway, hopefully deleting your temp storage will help solve your footprint problem.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, merge sorting with only n extra space uses an auxiliary array passed into the `merge()` and `mergesort()` functions. Then, instead of making a new helper array every time, you just use the same indices in the helper array as you're using in the current `merge()` call - that way, all of your `merge()` calls can do their thing without stepping on each other's toes.

Since your professor won't let you pass in any extra parameters, you're going to have to do something a little hacky to be able to use an auxiliary array - we'll use as much space on the end of the array we get passed in as we do for the array itself. Note that this requires you pass in an array twice as long as normal, half-filled with garbage (we just need the space) - and it also requires a little extra work to make sure you know where the helper array starts.

I'm going to try to avoid giving you exact code since this is homework - but the idea I used (I just got this working on my computer) was to keep a global variable called helper that was a pointer to the "end" of the array (or the beginning of your auxiliary array). Then, when you get into your `mergesort()` call, check if it's initialized - if not, point it to the beginning of the auxiliary array. Other than that your code can stay basically the same - but instead of creating a new array `helper[]` at the start of every merge function, just use the global one.

If anyone has a solution that doesn't involve using globals I'm all ears - but within the limitations, this works.